# How to create a save button in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, when we plot a graph it opens a figure window, which has a save button that allows the user to save figures in different file format.

I have created a GUI which plots a graph. Now I want a similar save button in my GUI, which works like the one in figure window.

What would be the code exactly for such push button? I tried `saveas()`, which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do you mean the button in the toolbar?

Comment: Or do you want a pushbutton which looks like save button which saves a plot with a given handle? I would guess that the second alternative is quite complicated.